# EvoStreaming problems with Websocket Secure WSS

Tags: ssl, websocket, streaming, wss

Now I'm using EvoStream service Evostream.com

It's working well with WebSocket WS

But can't work with WebSocket Secure WSS

I'm configuring in /etc/evostreamms/config.lua

```
-- WebSockets over SSL FMP4 Fetch
{
        ip="0.0.0.0",
        port=8420,
        protocol="inboundWSSFMP4",
        cipherSuite="HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5",
        sslKey="/etc/apache2/ssl_certs/server.key",
        sslCert="/etc/apache2/ssl_certs/certs.pem"
}
```

About Port opened 8420. I'm sure this port is working. I had swap using 8420 port for WS. And it's working well.

About certificate:

I'm bought certificate at: https://ssl-store.jp

My Webservice working well with SSLKey and SSLCert configure at Port 443.

About intermediate cert issue.

I already did this way:

```
9. Create Server cert file (.cer)
vim server.cer ==> Paste data on email to this .cer file

9. Create Intermediate cert file (.cer)
vim dvcacert.cer ==> Paste data on email to this .cer file

10. Concatenate server.cer and dvcacert.cer
cat server.cer dvcacert.cer > certs.pem
```

Checking thread processing

```
$ netstat -anp | grep 8420
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8420            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

But I'm always got this result

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://35.x.x.x:8420/13?progressive' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

Please help!
Thank you because had seen my question!